# laravel multiple parameter pass throught controller and show database first result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

how i show my index title and body from index table
this is my route
 which i have 2 parameter

```
Route::get('forum/{forumthread}/{forumindex}', [
    'uses'  =>  'ForumController@indexshow',
    'as'    =>  'forum.index.show'
    ]);
```

here is my controller

```
public function indexshow($slug){

    $forumindex = forumindex::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    $forumthread = forumthread::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    return view('forum.index.index', compact('forumthread', 'forumindex', ''));
}
```

here is my view

```
{{ $forumthread->thread }} // this is working 
{{ $forumindex->title }} //this is not working
```

help me to sort out this method thank you

Comment: What value do you get in `$forumindex`?

Comment: i got this error
ErrorException in dba860ec203f22e30de9d0f97c7aa47726f4bebf.php line 7:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\new\resources\views\forum\index\index.blade.php)

Comment: That's because you're passing only the first parameter. Only the forumthread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify all the parameters in your indexshow method,
Try this:

```
public function indexshow($head_slug, $index_slug){

    $forumindex = forumindex::where('slug', $index_slug)->first();

    $forumthread = forumthread::where('slug', $head_slug)->first();

    return view('forum.index.index', compact('forumthread', 'forumindex', ''));
}
```